# MSysGit Not finding Repo

Tags: windows, git

So I had a repo working by adding it to the htdocs in apache, however, I couldn't commit. So I set up SSH (I am using copSSH) and I can ssh into the server and see the files in my project.git. However I get the following when I try to clone...

> $ git clone un@server:/home/un/Repositories/git/test.git/
>
> Cloning into 'test'...
>
> un@server's password:
>
> fatal: '/home/un/Repositories/git/test.git/' does not appear to be a git re
> pository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops this did work...

> git clone un@server:Repositories/git/test.git/

Must be an environment var issue